# Эффективный поиск, значения по ключу, являющемся строкой

Tags: java, android, массивы, list

Здравствуйте.Имеется приложение в котором нужно вывести тв программу в формате epg

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Правая часть - каналы, левая - программа.Все это дело сделано через прорисовку в классе унаследованом от View.Каналы хранятся как

```
List<String Name,List<Program>>>
```

Тут необходимо организовать моментальный поиск по каналам.Сейчас идея такая.Перебирать List каналов при введенном символе.Но что то мне эта идея не нравится.Допустим 1000 каналов,ввел 4 буквы и получается мне нужно List перебрать 4 раза по 1000.Кто знает как правильно будет сделать такой поиск?

Answer (score 4):

Я думаю, к данной задаче, хорошо применимо [префиксное дерево](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE).
Выглядит оно так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Это дерево, *ассоциативный массив*. Ключами являются строки, а значения имеют произвольный тип. В каждом листе дерева содержится значение, а ребра хранят строки.
Если спуститься от корня по ребрам до листа, объединяя строки на пройденных ребрах, получим исходную строку -  ключ, по которому хранится значение.

Сложность поиска будет **линейная** от длины строки - ключа.

Comment: А пример кода есть?

Comment: https://github.com/izebit/Library/blob/master/src/main/java/ru/izebit/structs/tree/Trie.java - университетский код

Answer (score 0):

Мне кажется, в вашем случае, размер списка каналов достаточно небольшой для того, чтобы обычный поиск в списке работал быстро (вряд ли количество каналов будет в десятках тысяч) и проблема скорее в том, что поиск будет выполняться чаще, чем надо. В данном случае Вам достаточно добавить задержку на ввод пользователя, чтобы начинать поиск по каналам не сразу после ввода одного символа, а откладывать эту задачу, скажем, на 700 миллисекунд, тем самым давая пользователю время ввести больше символов и отправить запрос на поиск сразу по нескольким введённым символам.

Я полагаю, Вы используете `TextWatcher` для того, чтобы реагировать на пользовательский ввод. Наиболее простое решение сделать это с помощью класса `Handler`.

```
private Runnable delayedFiltering = null;

@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable input) {
    if (delayedFiltering != null) {
        getHandler().removeCallbacks(delayedFiltering);
    }
    delayedFiltering = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            performFiltering(input.toString());
        }
    }
    getHandler().postDelayed(delayedFiltering, 700);
}
```

Вы можете создать отдельный `HandlerThread` или просто воспользоваться методом `getHandler` вашего `TextView`. Главное, ни в коем случае не используйте `removeCallbacksAndMessages(null)` во втором случае.

Вместо того, чтобы каждый раз создавать новый анонимный `Runnable`, Вы можете создать собственный класс, реализующий этот интерфейс, добавить в него поле со строкой для поиска и обновлять это значение вместо создания нового `Runnable`

```
private class DelayedFilter implements Runnable {

    private String constraint;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        performFiltering(constraint);
    }
}

private DelayedFilter delayedFiltering = new DelayedFilter();

@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable input) {
    if (delayedFiltering != null) {
        getHandler().removeCallbacks(delayedFiltering);
    }
    delayedFiltering.constraint = input.toString();
    getHandler().postDelayed(delayedFiltering, 700);
}
```

Если Вы знакомы с реактивным программированием, то то же самое можно сделать с использованием библиотек RxJava и RxAndroid. Пример кода с помощью метода `debounce` есть [тут](https://github.com/kaushikgopal/RxJava-Android-Samples/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/morihacky/android/rxjava/fragments/DebounceSearchEmitterFragment.java)

Comment: Зачем какие то задержки по времени, это абсолютно не эффективно и не решает проблемы ввода нескольких символов, может пользователь в носу поковыряться решил ..почему бы просто не начинать фильтрацию после ввода определенного количества символов (например 3-ех), как это делается во всех нормальных фильтрах по вводу

Comment: Одно другому не мешает. То же самое начнётся после ввода четвертого, пятого и последующих символов.